# How to get the Photo using connect api

Tags: apex, visualforce, connect-api

Can anyone tell me how to get the chatter profile pic using connect api in visualforce page?
I need a sample code for this...Because I am new to connect api.

Thanks in advance
Karthick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need ConnectApi to get the photoURL

You can query User Object to get PhotoURL of any User ,The User object has SmallPhotoURL and LargePhotoURL as fields .This holds the profile photo of chatter

**Edit**

```
Blob image = attachment.body;//its the blob of your attachment body or blob data of your image
    //Call the Connect API to Change the Photo
     if(!Test.isRunningTest()){//Since for this we dont have any way of testing this we skip using isTesting Flag
                ConnectApi.BinaryInput b=new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(image,contenttype,'myimage');
                ConnectApi.ChatterUsers.setPhoto(null,userinfo.getUserId(),b);
     }
```

> You will need first blob data of your image and then construct connectapi.binary Input from that and then use setphoto to change photo of user.Set photo  pass userId and binary data

Comment: I know that  but im my requirement I have to upload photo and display photo using connect api.. please give some idea

Comment: Added the code so that it helps you .You will need first blob data of your image and then construct connectapi.binary Input from that and then use setphoto to change photo of user ,

Answer (score 0):

Dont need the api u can do it in profiles only and every thing which u edit for home page go to setup customize their